# Map over each value in hash-map

Tags: clojure, hashmap, functor

I have a hash-map.  I want to iterate over the values and replace each of them depending on the value's type.  If the value is an integer, replace it with `true`, and if not, replace it with `false`.  I want this to return a new hash-map with every value updated to either true or false.

```
(defn my-function [hash-map]
  (loop [hash-map hash-map]
    (for [value (vals hash-map)]
      (if (= Integer (type value))
        (recur (assoc hash-map key true))
        (recur (assoc hash-map key false))))))
```

That won't work because Clojure `Can only recur from tail position`, but that's the general idea of what I want to do.  Any ideas of an effective way to do this?  `if-let` and `update-in` seemed like potential solutions, but I can't quite grasp them.

Comment: I've retagged the question to describe the nature of the problem instead of one possible way of implementing a solution.  Is that fine?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
(reduce-kv (fn [m k v] (assoc m k (= Integer (type v)))) {} m)
```

Or even shorter if you prefer:

```
(reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (= Integer (type %3))) {} m)
```

And to keep the type of map (hash vs. sorted):

```
(reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (= Integer (type %3))) (empty m) m)
```

Caveat: the last one doesn't work with records.

Answer (score 5):

The operation you've outlined -- transforming each value in a map, independently -- is actually already implemented in [the Functor module](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/generic.functor-api.html).

What you need to do to use it is implement your function that transforms a single value, then `fmap` it over your map:

```
(fmap your-function your-map)
```

*(Don't be misled by the name fmap -- this operation is not specific to maps.  Since it's a generic function, it works on anything that has a Functor instance, which also includes lists, sets, and vectors).*  This is a structure-preserving operation:  none of the keys will be changed, no new ones will be added, none will be removed.

If you'd prefer to avoid using a generic function, just check out [the implementation](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/2ede388a9267d175bfaa7781ee9d57532eb4f20f/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/generic/functor.clj#L34):

```
(defmethod fmap clojure.lang.IPersistentMap
  [f m]
  (into (empty m) (for [[k v] m] [k (f v)])))  ;;; <== the important part!!
```

where `f = your-function` and `m = your-map`.

---

This library has been moved (is moving?  will be moved?) to `clojure.algo.generic.functor`.  See [this](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go) for more information, and [this](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/generic/functor.clj) for the source.

Comment: This is simple enough that pulling in functors would be pretty weird.

Comment: @Rayne Not sure what the point of your comment is since I said `if you'd prefer to avoid using a generic function ...`.

Comment: The point of my comment was merely to point out that it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to pull in functors for this specific task. I didn't mean anything by it. Don't take it personally!

Comment: @Rayne again, not sure what the point of repeating something mentioned in the post is.

Comment: @MattFenwick any idea where in which ns is the fmap now ?

Comment: @murtaza52 wow, I'm surprised to find that it moved.  It [looks](http://clojure.github.io/algo.generic/clojure.algo.generic.functor-api.html) like it might be in `clojure.algo.generic.functor` now.

Answer (score 3):

```
(letfn [(map-vals [m f]
          (into {} (for [[k v] m]
                     [k (f v)])))]
  (map-vals m #(= Integer (type %))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn f [m]
  (reduce (fn [res [k v]] 
            (assoc res k (= Integer (type v)))) 
          {} m))
```

Or if you need recursion version

```
(defn f 
  ([m] (f {} m))
  ([res m] (if (empty? m)
             res
             (let [[k v] (first m)]
               (recur (assoc res k (= Integer (type v))) 
                      (rest m))))))
```